# Using System.Random

Tags: c#, random, integer

I'm using C# in .NET Framework 3.5 and am trying to generate a random integer by using Random(). My code is here:

```
using System.Random;

int randomNumber;
Random RNG = new Random();
randomNumber = RNG.Next(1,10);
```

I think everything should be alright, but I'm getting the error that System.Random isn't a valid namespace, but I'm pretty sure it is...

Anybody know what's the problem or some other method I should be using to generate a random integer within a range?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/random should help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Random` is a class in the `System` namespace. Change the first line to just `using System;` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 7):

The Random class is a part of the `System` namespace, not `System.Random`. You can reference the type directly using the namespace though:

```
System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
```

Or..

```
using System;

Random rnd = new Random();
```

Answer (score 5):

You only have to use the System-Namespace

```
using System;

int randomNumber;
Random RNG = new Random();
randomNumber = RNG.Next(1,10);
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You don't need the using statement.</strike> Your using statement is invalid.

Random is a class in System namespace. Simply use

```
using System;
```

instead of 
    using System.Random;